# Ruby gem 'Mail' setting up with SMTP

Tags: ruby, smtp

So I am testing out the Ruby gem `'Mail'`. Below is my code. According to the sysadmin, there is no authentication necessary to send out by SMTP and the server is allowed to send by SMTP. If that makes sense.

I have used the `'net/smtp'` which worked fine but I can't seem to get this `'Mail'` gem to work for me. It's not giving me any errors so I'm not sure what the issue is. I am a complete ruby noob at this.

```
#testing out mailer
require 'mail'
Mail.defaults do
    delivery_method :smtp,  {
    :address => '10.18.34.18',
    :port => '25',
    :user_name => 'anonymous',
    :password => 'anonymous',
    :authentication => 'plain',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true}
end

mail = Mail.new do
    from 'server@company.com'
    to 'cvu@company.com'
    subject 'This is a test email'
    body File.read('test.txt')
end

mail.to_s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `mail.deliver!`, calling `to_s` just returns you a string representation of the object.

Alternatively you can call `deliver` with a block instead of calling `new`, e.g.

```
mail = Mail.deliver do
    from 'server@company.com'
    to 'cvu@company.com'
    subject 'This is a test email'
    body File.read('test.txt')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what struthersneil stated, I had to remove the authentication like so:

```
require 'mail'
Mail.defaults do
    delivery_method :smtp,  {
    :address => '10.18.34.18',
    :port => '25',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true}
end
```